# Reactjs- I keep getting the error: TypeError: companies.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to display mysql data to a table using nodejs and reactjs.
For some reasom I keep the folowing error:

TypeError: companies.map is not a function

I have been trying to figure out the issue since yesterday but no luck.
I have even passed an empty array to useState but that does not work.

If someone can help me figure out the issue with my code, that'd be great.

My code is as follows:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Container, Row, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

const AllCompanies = () => {
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCompanies();
  }, []);

  const getAllCompanies = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/companymst");
    console.log(response.data);
    setCompanies(response.data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Table striped bordered hover size="sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>CompanyCode</th>
                    <th>CompanyName</th>
                    <th>Address1</th>
                    <th>Address2</th>
                    <th>PoBox</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Province</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Fax</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>RegistrationNo</th>
                    <th>VatNo</th>
                    <th>PinNo</th>
                    <th>BranchNo</th>
                    <th>BranchHq</th>
                    <th>StartDate</th>
                    <th>EndDate</th>
                    <th>Current</th>
                    <th>RunDate</th>
                    <th>DateCreated</th>
                    <th>UserID</th>
                    <th>LocationID</th>
                    <th colSpan="2">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {companies.map((company) => {
                    return (
                      <tr>
                        <td>{company.CompanyCode}</td>
                        <td>{company.CompanyName}</td>
                        <td>{company.Address1}</td>
                        <td>{company.Address2}</td>
                        <td>{company.PoBox}</td>
                        <td>{company.City}</td>
                        <td>{company.Province}</td>
                        <td>{company.Province}</td>
                        <td>{company.Country}</td>
                        <td>{company.Phone}</td>
                        <td>{company.Fax}</td>
                        <td>{company.Email}</td>
                        <td>{company.RegistrationNo}</td>
                        <td>{company.VatNo}</td>
                        <td>{company.PinNo}</td>
                        <td>{company.BranchNo}</td>
                        <td>{company.BranchHq}</td>
                        <td>{company.StartDate}</td>
                        <td>{company.EndDate}</td>
                        <td>{company.Current}</td>
                        <td>{company.RunDate}</td>
                        <td>{company.DateCreated}</td>
                        <td>{company.UserID}</td>
                        <td>{company.LocationID}</td>
                        <td>
                          <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <Button variant="danger">Delete</Button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    );
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </Table>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AllCompanies;
```

Comment: I'd willing to bet that `response.data` is an object and not an array. console.log it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @captain-yossarian saying, might be you are getting object, to avoid this issue you can do like below.

```
{companies?.length > 0 && companies.map((company) => {
   return '';
})}
```

Comment: This did mke the error go away, but now the issue at hand is that I have no data displaying iin my table

Comment: if you are getting object array then and then it will display records.
your data should be like this 
[{name:"john",email:"abc@gmail.com",message:"Hello"},{name:"Doe",email:"bcd@gmail.com",message:"Hello 123"}]

Comment: result: Array(1)
0: {CmpnyCode: "2", CmpnyName: "Comapny1", Address1: "Address1", Address2: "Address2 at sth", PoBox: "359", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

This was I get when I console.log(response.data)

Comment: <td>{company.CompanyCode}</td>
 <td>{company.CompanyName}</td>
whatever keys you are getting in reponse and whatever you are trying to access both are different.
please log the "company" inside map function.

Comment: No changes. Still getting a blank table

Comment: jsfiddle.net/au0cgfb5/1  check here